# Failed to show data retrieved from Firebase in RecyclerView

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I believe my recyclerView have successfully retrieve data from firebase because it shows 2 cardView inside my recycler view, which is the same number of data allocated inside my firebase under Menu.

[image: Firebase Image]

[Screenshot of my RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7iGR.png).

I have 3 classes which are listOnline2, MyAdapter and cMenu. There are an array inside both lisOnline2 and MyAdapter. I use array in listOnline2 store retrieved data from firebase and array in MyAdapter to view data inside cardview. Below are my codings for the class listOnline2.

```
`DatabaseReference currentUserRef,counterRef, ref;
MyAdapter adapterR;

RecyclerView listOnline21;
ArrayList <cMenu> menu;
private static final String TAG = "listOnline2";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_list_online2 );

    listOnline21= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
    listOnline21.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( listOnline2.this ) );
    listOnline21.setHasFixedSize(true);
menu= new ArrayList<cMenu>();


    counterRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Menu" ).child( "twRAlXRMSgPkA35nmMoFAuAsTdz1" );
    Log.d( TAG, "Clicked ID: "+idd );
    currentUserRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Menu").child( FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() );

    counterRef.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                cMenu p=dataSnapshot1.getValue(cMenu.class);
                menu.add(p);

            }
            Log.d( TAG, "Data of array: "+menu );
            adapterR=new MyAdapter( listOnline2.this, menu );
            listOnline21.setAdapter( adapterR );
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(listOnline2.this, "Opsss.... Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } );

    Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Food Ordering Delivery System");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate( R.menu.main_menu,menu );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_cart:
            Intent toCart=new Intent( listOnline2.this, Cart.class );
            startActivity( toCart );
            break;

        case R.id.action_logout:
            Intent toLogin=new Intent( listOnline2.this, LoginActivity.class );
            startActivity( toLogin );

            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
}`
```

Meanwhile, below are my codes in MyAdapter class

```
DatabaseReference currentUserRef,counterRef;
MyAdapter adapterR;

RecyclerView listOnline21;
ArrayList <cMenu> menu;
private static final String TAG = "listOnline2";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_list_online2 );

    listOnline21= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
    listOnline21.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( listOnline2.this ) );
    listOnline21.setHasFixedSize(true);
       menu= new ArrayList<cMenu>();


    counterRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Menu" ).child( "twRAlXRMSgPkA35nmMoFAuAsTdz1" );
    Log.d( TAG, "Clicked ID: "+idd );
    currentUserRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Menu").child( FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() );

    counterRef.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                cMenu p=dataSnapshot1.getValue(cMenu.class);
                menu.add(p);

            }
            Log.d( TAG, "Data of array: "+menu );
            adapterR=new MyAdapter( listOnline2.this, menu );
            listOnline21.setAdapter( adapterR );
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(listOnline2.this, "Opsss.... Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } );

    Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Food Ordering Delivery System");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate( R.menu.main_menu,menu );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_cart:
            Intent toCart=new Intent( listOnline2.this, Cart.class );
            startActivity( toCart );
            break;

        case R.id.action_logout:
            Intent toLogin=new Intent( listOnline2.this, LoginActivity.class );
            startActivity( toLogin );

            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
}
```

And the last class is cMenu is as follows:

```
private String fName, fDesc, fImage, fQuantity, fPrice, fId;

public cMenu() {
}

public cMenu(String fName, String fDesc, String fImage, String fQuantity, String fPrice, String fId) {
    this.fName = fName;
    this.fDesc = fDesc;
    this.fImage = fImage;
    this.fQuantity = fQuantity;
    this.fPrice = fPrice;
    this.fId = fId;
}

public String getfName() {
    return fName;
}

public void setfName(String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}

public String getfDesc() {
    return fDesc;
}

public void setfDesc(String fDesc) {
    this.fDesc = fDesc;
}

public String getfImage() {
    return fImage;
}

public void setfImage(String fImage) {
    this.fImage = fImage;
}

public String getfQuantity() {
    return fQuantity;
}

public void setfQuantity(String fQuantity) {
    this.fQuantity = fQuantity;
}

public String getfPrice() {
    return fPrice;
}

public void setfPrice(String fPrice) {
    this.fPrice = fPrice;
}

public String getfId() {
    return fId;
}

public void setfId(String fId) {
    this.fId = fId;
}
```

What can I do to display data from the Array that I stored data retrieved from my Firebase? Please give me a suggestion because I spend 2 days starring at these codes. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! I change 3 variable from cMenu class.

> fName to menuName
>
> fDesc to foodDescription
>
> fPrice to price

The reason why those variable need to change in order to view data from firebase is that variables from the setter getter class need to have the same variable name as in the database. You can view my database screenshot in the question section. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

int id=FirebaseAuth.getInstance.getCurrentUser.getUid();
    currentUserRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Menu").child(id);

Comment: Sorry, under my menu its not the current user's id. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

put in `OnCreate method`

```
adapterR=new MyAdapter( listOnline2.this, menu );
listOnline21.setAdapter( adapterR );
```

Use this line `onDataChange method`

```
adapterR.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I think recyclerView can't notifyDataSetChanged. Only adapters can. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes sorry my bad only adapter can notifyDataSetChanged